# how to batch resize and crop with imagemagick and mogrify

Tags: resize, imagemagick, batch-processing, crop, mogrify

I have a directory of hundreds of pngs of mixed dimensions. Using imagemagick and mogrify I want to:

1. RESIZE the image to 512px -- if width is smaller then that is 512, if height is smaller than that is 512
2. CROP the wider dimension to 512 to make a 512x512 square

any help appreciated, having a heck of a time understanding the imagemagick docs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to resize only if the image is smaller than 512 in either dimension, so as to enlarge it to 512x512 preserving aspect ratio.  And you want to pad (not crop) so that the result is exactly 512x512. And you want to process only PNGs.  Then you can do that as follows in ImageMagick 6 in Unix.

```
create a new directory to hold the output, so that you do not overwrite

cd to directory containing the images

mogrify -format png -path path/to/new_directory -resize "512x512<" -background white -gravity center -extent 512x512 *.png
```

If using ImageMagick 7, change `mogrify` to `magick mogrify`.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my little edit. I clarified that `mogrify` and `magick mogrify` are commands you type in the shell/Terminal by surrounding them with backticks.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. No problem

Comment: ah thank you that sort of worked, it cropped everything 512x512 in the center but it didn't resize things first? thank you though!

Comment: It only resizes for images that are smaller than 512x512 as per your request. If you need it for only larger images, then change < to >. If you want it to resize for all images, then remove <.